# Limit of $\left(\frac{n^2+2}{2n^2+1}\right)^{n^2}$

Tags: limits

The limit to solve is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^2+2}{2n^2+1}\right)^{n^2}$$
I tried to use L'Hôpital's rule but the derivatives are quite complex.

Comment: Do you realise the bracketed fraction tends to $\frac12$?

Comment: Hint for an alternative approach: First determine $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln \left( \frac{n^2 + 2}{2n^2 + 1} \right)^{n^2}$.

Comment: Notably, $(1/2)^\infty$ is **not** an indeterminate form

Comment: @MichaelJoyce: That is complicating the problem unnecessarily.

Comment: Right. To clarify I will just add that in this case you can use L'Hopital if you get an indeterminate like $0^\infty$. You don't have that here. So no L'Hopital.

Comment: @Clayton: Perhaps, but it depends on what knowledge you bring to the problem. Logarithms are useful for turning problems about exponentiation into problems about multiplication. That alone is worthwhile to appreciate, even it is admittedly overkill in this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

Observe that

$$\frac{n^2+2}{2n^2+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac12\implies \exists\;N\in\Bbb N\;\;s.t.\;\;n>N\implies\frac12-0.01<\frac{n^2+2}{2n^2+1}<\frac12+0.01$$

Can you see now how to use the squeeze theorem?

Comment: For a slightly easier lower bound, you can use $0$. This way you only need to worry about modifying the upper bound.